# /usr/local/Library/Homebrew/shims/super/sed: No such file or directory

Tags: homebrew, phpize

The following error occurs when I execute phpize：

> /usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.38/bin/phpize: line 61: /usr/local/Library/Homebrew/shims/super/sed: No such file or directory
>   /usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.38/bin/phpize: line 62: /usr/local/Library/Homebrew/shims/super/sed: No such file or directory
>   /usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.38/bin/phpize: line 63: /usr/local/Library/Homebrew/shims/super/sed: No such file or directory
>   Configuring for:
>   PHP Api Version:
>   Zend Module Api No:
>   Zend Extension Api No:
>   /usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.38/bin/phpize: line 155: /usr/local/Library/Homebrew/shims/super/sed: No such file or directory
>   autoheader: error: AC_CONFIG_HEADERS not found in configure.in

Is there a way to solve it？Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is a know [bug](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-php/issues/3572).

But it's now corrected. Running :

```
brew update
brew upgrade
```

Should solve it.